# Log in only by email and no username

Tags: login

Can you tell me a function to insert in the `functions.php` file to remove the login via username option?

I would like the user to be able to log in only with his registered email.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the filter `authenticate`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate

Comment: I think so, can you give me the exact code to allow users to access only via email and password? Without using the username? Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that embedding this in the theme will mean on any theme change it'll be impossible to login as nobody would know their usernames. Put it in an `mu-plugin` or a normal plugin. It'll be just as fast, except now it'll work for all themes, and can be copied between sites easily. Putting functionality like this inside a theme is very bad practice, themes should only contain visuals/styles/templates

Comment: Hi, @MatteoFeduzi, I'm glad I could help you progress towards a solution. You may not be aware but the community is not terribly fond of "write my code" questions seeing them as "do my homework for me". See [this discussion](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/483/109240) for a more in-depth look at question and answer standards regarding code.

Answer (score 0):

In [default-filters](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.3/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L425) you'll see

```
// Default authentication filters
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password', 20, 3 );
```

so you just need to

```
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20 );
```